# CSP error for image embed to GitHub with Firefox web extension content script

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can't add image to GitHub issue page with firefox web extension content script.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading 
of a resource at         
https://api.everhour.com/avatar/MjM4XzE0OTA3MTAyNDIuMTY0OTEx.png (“img-
src https://github.com data: https://assets-cdn.github.com 
https://identicons.github.com https://collector.githubapp.com 
https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com 
https://*.githubusercontent.com”).
```

I've tried set img-src policies in manifest.json, but it does not work.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://api.everhour.com"
}
```

Does anybody know how to ignore page CSP policies in web extension?

Comment: I can see a couple of "bad" solutions there, like editing the page's CSP or pretending to serve from whitelisted domains, both with `webRequest`.. But I wonder if using `<canvas>` instead in some clever way would work around it.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for response! Thought about `<canvas>` and inline image sources, but I need also allow websocket connection which get blocked by CSP as well. I didn't try to modify request with webRequest, but I expect there should be a more clear solution for web extensions. If I didn't find something easier I will move with webRequest.

Comment: For websocket you can certainly try to proxy it: your background talks to websocket, and communicates with the content script with its own protocol. Images though can be harder..

Comment: On the other hand, surgically editing CSP of the page (as long as you don't strip it blind) seems to be an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: The issue with background script is that it reloads only with browser restart, but websocket can be accidentally closed and did not recovered after. We use ably.io which is quite stable, but there are still cases appear when websocket connection completely closed in background script. But proxy is definitely an option. Also the issue with CSP appear only in Firefox and only for GitHub which will force me to support separate implementation for Chrome/Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].